# Matrix / Vector bracket - Transposed

Tags: matrices, vectors, transpose

I have the following question:
H is a positiv definite matrix, $\lambda$ is a number, $c,x$ and $d$ are vectors

why is

$0=(H(x+\lambda d)+c)^Td = d^THx+\lambda d^THd+d^Tc$

I thought: $(A+B)^T = A^T+B^T$

So I have no idea, why the vector $d$ (right of the bracket) become $d^T$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
0=(H(x+\lambda d)+c)^Td
\end{equation}
Transposing the whole equation bearing in mind the the left hand side is the scalar zero so it won't change after transpose as well as keeping in mind that $(Bz)^T=z^TB^T$ and $(z^T)^T = z$, we get:

\begin{equation}
[(H(x+\lambda d)+c)^Td ]^T=d^T(H(x+\lambda d)+c) = 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= d^THx+\lambda d^THd+d^Tc
\end{equation}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/528659)

Comment: Yes, it does provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Well, in my opinion your answer behaves more like a hint - which is fine as a comment or if it is a more convoluted one as an answer. Clearly the OP is not aware of how matrix multiplication behaves under transposing. So I suggest that you add this and maybe which line you see in question and then I think we have a proper answer.

Comment: @user190080 : I edited the answer per your comments.

Comment: great - thank you very much